# CustomerInfo nickname and reference_id usage in different platforms

Tags: square-connect

I find that the nickname and reference_id fields work differently across platforms and I'd like to get clarification on how they should be used.

1. With the API, I can retrieve and set both these fields.
2. In the web-based dashboard, both fields are displayed and can be edited if present, but there's no way to enter a nickname when creating a new customer.
3. In the Register iOS app, none of these fields are shown or editable. They're also absent when creating a new customer.

What I want to do is map Square Customers to our existing members, but we're facing three problems:

1. *reference_id* seems to map perfectly with our existing member numbers but, as mentioned, it's nowhere to be seen in the Register app.
2. Searching customers in the Register app only searches in names and emails. It would really help us if it searched in *reference_id* as well.
3. CustomerGroupInfo is read-only via the API (and not even an endpoint). We would map these to our membership levels.

As of now, I'm looking at ugly workarounds, but I wanted to know if something in the roadmap could help us out. Thanks in advance to the people at Square!

Comment: I'm a little confused, is there a problem in pulling the customers from the API?

Comment: I probably asked too many questions at the same time. The API works exactly as documented.My main issue concerns the way the _nickname_ and _reference_id_ field are made available in the web dashboard and in the Register app, which is inconsistent. I would have liked some official advice as to why this is so and which of _reference_id_ or _nickname_ is more likely to be made available in the Register app eventually.

Comment: Dashboard and Register have somewhat different use cases, so they display slightly different pieces of information. I wouldn't expect the `reference_id` to be added to the Register app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How about `nickname`, then? Any chance of it being added to the Register app?

Comment: Let me rephrase, I wouldn't rely on any future changes to the Square Register app.